# chown: invalid user nginx on centos

Tags: nginx, centos, chown

When I type

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /home/abcxyz.com
```

I get an error:

```
chown: invalid user: ‘nginx:nginx’
```

I research many pages but solution still not found.
Any help? thanks

Comment: It would seem that you have run `chown -R ‘nginx:nginx‘ /home/abcxyz.com` (with extraneous quotes), as opposed to the command without quotes as you stated in your question.